# Send Cloudwatch logs to Loki

Tags: logging, amazon-cloudwatch, fluentd

I have a k8s cluster where I installed Loki to keep track of all the Pods' logs. I also have an AWS API gateway that sends API requests to a service in my cluster.
I also enable Cloudwatch logs for the API Gateway.
I am looking for a way to retrieve these Cloudwatch logs and send them to Loki, so I have all the logs in one place.
I saw I should use Fluentd / Fluent bit, but I am not sure how to implement it.
I am reading the documentation and I can see there is an output plugin for Loki but I can't understand what to use as an input plugin and how to configure it.
Could anyone give me some suggestions or point me to some resource/document/how-to/anything that can help me?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: These docs might be helpful: https://docs.fluentd.org/v/0.12/articles and  https://docs.fluentd.org/v/0.12/articles/docker-logging.